# How can I replace G5.3 halogen ceiling can lights with flat-panel LEDs?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting, replacement

I've got a half-dozen halogen ceiling can lights that I'd like to replace with LEDs.  The existing bulbs are 12vAC with G.53 bases, and the can sticker says it accepts 50w max.  I don't want to just replace the bulbs with LED "bulbs" - the existing swivel mounts (my wife calls them "eyeball lights") are all wrong for the space.  In other parts of the house, I've used LED-retrofit panels that are 120vAC and have an E26 "plug" at the end, to screw into the pre-existing socket in the can (*e.g.*, [Commercial Electric's](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5-6-in-Color-Temperature-Selectable-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Trim-4-Pack-NS01cA09FR2-259/309010790)).  I cannot find anything vaguely similar for 12vAC.  **Am I stuck pulling the existing cans and trying to get new ones in without messing up my ceiling?**

**Update**: The cans have individual transformers - there is a junction box mounted alongside each can.  These assemblies are what I'd describe as "new construction" style - the junction box is attached to arms that are nailed into the ceiling joists, and the can itself is friction-fit into a ring attached to the junction box.  I can't see an easy way forward to removing these old fixtures. :-(

Comment: Do you know if each of your existing cans has its own 12V transformer or power supply? Are you able to non-destructively pull the can from the ceiling and look in the hole?

Comment: @brhans I suspect the cans have individual transformers, but finding out will  be a big piece of work.  If it gets to there, I'll probably hire a pro and just say "Make it so."

Comment: the cans should come out fairly easily once you figure out what  bit you need to manipulate to make them let go of the ceiling. be sure to unstick the can rim from the ceiling paint first.

Comment: If you can find 12V cans that can somehow by physically mounted to the existing ones, you could bypass the G53 sockets and just splice the new cans to the old transformers using any method that's suitable for 12V.  The new cans don't have to be designed as screw-in retrofits like the ones you're describing, they. just have to be able to fit and be secured.